# How can I find out the command line corresponding to choosing an application to open a file in desktop environment?

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments, lxde, pcmanfm

How can I find out the command line corresponding to choosing an application to open a file in pcmanfm under lxde?

I thought I would find something under `~/.local/share/applications` by `grep -R -i masterpdf .`, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try with just `master` and look in `/usr/share/applications` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the example you choose is `masterpdfeditor4` 
for me, when I want to find out the command that belongs to a desktop app. 
after opening the app. ' ps -A ' to find out which process is created. then the name would be the command used to open the application in terminal.